# How can I upload my custom data on google analytics by using custom Dimension/Metrics in iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am trying to upload my custom data by using my iOS application

```
[self.tracker setCustom:1 metric:[NSNumber numberWithInt:9]];
```

and

```
[self. tracker  setCustom:2 dimension:@"Test2"];
```

I have followed all the instruction provided by google document and i have used https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v2/customdimsmets

Where can I see the custom data that I have uploaded from `iOS` application?

Please let me know if anybody can help me for uploading custom data from iOS to Google Analytics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The google document says:

> Set a custom dimension value just before the send call to which you
>   want the value applied.The defined scope of the custom dimension will
>   determine at processing time which additional hits may be associated
>   with that value.

That means a custom dimension is belong to a hit action(such as: sendView,sendAction).In your code, i cann't find any send call !

Sample code about custom dimension:

```
// Get the tracker object.
id tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance].defaultTracker;

// Set the dimension value for index 1.
[tracker setCustom:1
         dimension:@"myValue"];

// Dimension value is associated and sent with this hit.
[tracker sendView:screenName];
```

Hope it could help you.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I am still strugling Where can I see the dimension value uploaded on the google analytics

Comment: @PushpendraSingh how about have a look this article about Access Custom Dimensions in Google Analytics:http://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2013/09/10/access-custom-dimensions-google-analytics/#sr=g&m=o&cp=or&ct=-tmc&st=hpphmf%20dvtupn%20ejnfotjpo&ts=1384845402

Comment: I think we are diverting from the track.I want to see the data here: https://www.google.com/analytics/web/?authuser=0#report/app-overview